# Android open Fragment with Animation

Tags: android, spring, animation

I am new in android. I want to add some animations to open fragment with clicking on Floating action Button. And also required some Spring Rebound Example to Animate view. I search on google but no examples are there. Please help me to find Rebound Spring Example and Animation examples. Thank you.

Comment: Please read i also want some spring rebound example..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the new android.animation framework (object animators) with FragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations as well as with FragmentTransaction.setTransition.

Here's an example on using setCustomAnimations from ApiDemos' FragmentHideShow.java:

ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out);
and here's the relevant animator XML from res/animator/fade_in.xml:

```
<objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_quad"
    android:valueFrom="0"
    android:valueTo="1"
    android:propertyName="alpha"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
```

Note that you can combine multiple animators using `<set>`, just as you could with the older animation framework.

EDIT: Since folks are asking about slide-in/slide-out, I'll comment on that here.

Slide-in and slide-out
You can of course animate the translationX, translationY, x, and y properties, but generally slides involve animating content to and from off-screen. As far as I know there aren't any translation properties that use relative values. However, this doesn't prevent you from writing them yourself. Remember that property animations simply require getter and setter methods on the objects you're animating (in this case views), so you can just create your own getXFraction and setXFraction methods on your view subclass, like so:

```
public class MyFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {
    ...
    public float getXFraction() {
        return getX() / getWidth(); // TODO: guard divide-by-zero
    }

    public void setXFraction(float xFraction) {
        // TODO: cache width
        final int width = getWidth();
        setX((width > 0) ? (xFraction * width) : -9999);
    }
    ...
}
```

Now you can animate the 'xFraction' property, like so:

**res/animator/slide_in.xml:**

```
<objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:valueFrom="-1.0"
    android:valueTo="0"
    android:propertyName="xFraction"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
```

Note that if the object you're animating in isn't the same width as its parent, things won't look quite right, so you may need to tweak your property implementation to suit your use case.

Comment: please give me some advance and custom animation.

Comment: You'll have to make it on your own dear.

Comment: for more details refer http://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html

Comment: Try this out: http://facebook.github.io/rebound/

Comment: but i need some more examples...